# Difference in setting the coordinates of the center a circle using the half of the view and directly

Tags: android

My question is about difference in  setting the coordinates of the center a circle using  the half of the view and  directly. My device is `240 * 320` and when I use the `getWidht()/2` and the `getHeight()` methods to draw a circle in center of the screen I am successful. But when I use the `120` value instead the `getWidth/2` and the `160` value instead the `getHight()/2` , I can not draw the circle in center of the screen. while I think the `getWidth()/2` value is equal to the `120` value and the `getHeight()/2` value is equal to the `160` value.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        C c;
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.re);
            c = new C(getApplicationContext());
                    relativeLayout.addView(c);
        }
    }

    class C extends  View {

        Paint paint;
        C(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint = new Paint();
        }

      @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          paint.setAntiAlias(true);
      paint.setColor(Color.RED);
      canvas.drawCircle(120,160,20,paint);//this is not in the center of the screen.

canvas.drawCircle(getWidth/2, getHeight/2, 20 , paint);// But this is in center of the screen
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you print the getWidth and getHeight? It maybe not 160 and 120, because it according to your views size, sometime the size it will reduce the status bar on some Android device...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. because the `relativeLayout` object has `padding` attribute. I should remove the padding attributes from the `relativeLayout` object. For more information please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521470/does-the-fill-parent-or-match-parent-attributes-work-for-a-relativelayout-object?noredirect=1#comment52900604_32521470).