# Does the fill_parent or match_parent attributes work for a relativeLayout object really

Tags: android

Does the fill_parent  or match_parent attributes work for a `relativeLayout` object really?

Please see the following image:

[image]

Comment: Post the layout file.

Comment: remove the paddings from your xml.I can tell that without looking at your layout.

Answer (score 2):

`match_parent` works on any view.
As long as you don't have margins assigned to offset your view, it will expand to its parent size.

As for why you see it like this - do not rely too much on Android Studio designer. It is there to show a rough picture but is not a precise tool to rely on.
Best case to see things are fine:

- set a temporary different background color for your view (`RelativeLayout` in your case) and its parent layout
- load the app and check if the parent color is shown around your relative layout

Comment: `As long as you don't have margins assigned` or paddings.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Margins is the offset between the view and its parent. Paddings is the offset between the view and its children inside. So technically speaking, based on the difference seen on the screenshot (the `RelativeLayout` view and its parent) is existence of margins and no connection with paddings.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the lesson.